# Spice Simulation of EMI in Long Parallel Wires?

Tags: electromagnetism, wire, ltspice

I was thinking about using an external power supply for multiple pieces of analog audio gear. But it occurs to me that even if I use separate grounds for power and signal, because the wires would run alongside one another, changes in current on the power ground (from a power amplifier driving a 600 ohm load for example) would electromagnetically induce currents in the supposedly clean signal ground. Is this correct?

If yes, how can I model this in LTSpice? I assume it would just be two inductors coupled to some degree. Can someone explain roughly how to model EMI in long parallel wires?

Answer (score 1):

One way to analyze wires is to use NEC (Numerical Electrical Code). There are quite a few frontends for NEC which make life easier, as it requires numerical input, and spews out a lot of numbers.

But it allows you to simulate wires of any shape and position, induce voltages and/or currents, and determine the impedance and voltages.

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.qsl.net/4nec2/Tutorial.pdf), or this nice article in QST in 4 parts ([Part 1](http://wireless.ictp.it/school_2005/download/nec2/nec_part1.pdf), [part 2](http://wireless.ictp.it/school_2005/download/nec2/nec_part2.pdf), [part 3](http://wireless.ictp.it/school_2005/download/nec2/nec_part3.pdf), [part 4](http://wireless.ictp.it/school_2005/download/nec2/nec_part4.pdf)).